# Time complexity of for loop

Tags: java, c++, loops, for-loop, time-complexity

Is it O(n) or O(n*n)?

The loop runs approximately n*n times but the loop variable is only one.

I'm confused whether it's O(n) algorithm
I think it should be O(n*n) but gfg says it's O(n)

Can anybody help me with the answer??

```
int j=0;
for(int i=1; i<=n; )
{
   if(j<i)
   {
     j++;
     continue;
   }

   if(j==i)
   {
     i++;
     j=0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the loop runs `n * n` times? (On closer inspection I think you're right because `i` doesn't increment every time the loop runs, but it'd be good to hear your reasoning on this.)

Comment: The loop has no side effects, can be dropped by a compiler resulting in time complexity O(1).

Comment: *The loop runs approximately n*n times* -- As stated previously, a C++ compiler may just remove that entire loop, because all it does is spin wheels and does really nothing that affects any other part of a larger program.

Comment: *but gfg says it's O(n)* -- If they say that's the answer, why not discuss this over there at "gfg"?  Or you did that, and they told you "sorry, you're wrong"?  They have a discussion forum, no?  Also, that "gfg" site is not one I would recommend to learn C++ programming, if that's your goal.

Comment: It is not an algorithm as it does nothing. The j it changes is again 0 after it is over. So conforming C++ implementation may erase the for loop as optimization.

Answer (score 4):

This is O(1 + 2 + ... + n + n), that is the sum of the arithmetic progression 1 till n plus n, the sum is O(n * (n + 1) / 2 + n) ≈ O(n²).

Comment: I believe it is `1 + 2 + ... + n + n`

Comment: @u Great catch, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I think this loop runs 1 + 2 + ... + n times because `j` needs to be incremented `i - 1` times as `i` grows, and `i` grows `n` times. That gives a time complexity of O(n^2).